# How to show properties page programatically when clicking the customized icon on the toolbar in Eclipse Plugin development?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse Plugin development. I have already customized my main menu and toolbar, as well as properties page. Now I want to have something like: whenever the user clicks the customized icon on the toolbar, it will show the properties page as if the user selects the project and right-clicks on properties and show it, anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(Shell, IAdaptable, String, String[], Object)` to open a property dialog:

```
IProject project = ...;
PreferenceDialog createPropertyDialogOn(window.getShell(), project, 
    myPropertyPageId, new String[] { myPropertyPageId }, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```